# Easier way to grab parent route params - angular router

Tags: angular, angular-routing

**Update with solution**

As per @JBNizet's helpful comment below, the solution to access all route parameters from any route is to set `paramsInheritanceStrategy` to `'always'` in the root router config ExtraOptions:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(
  routes,
  {
    paramsInheritanceStrategy: 'always',
  },
)
```

**Original Question**

I need to subscribe to route params. Angular has a way of doing this with ActivatedRoute. However, from what I can tell, a param can only be accessed if the ActivatedRoute is an instance on the route that actually has the param.

E.g., if I'm looking for the param `:id` in the ActivatedRoute, but I'm currently on the route `/:id/some/child/route`, then I cannot access `id` directly through the current AR instance. I would have to traverse up through the AR to get the correct instance. Example:

```
constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

const param = this.activatedRoute.pathFromRoot[4].snapshot.params['id];

// or perhaps..
const param = this.activatedRoute.parent.parent.parent.snapshot.params['id];
```

This is cumbersome for deeper paths. Another technique would also be to split the router url and retrieve the desired param(s) that way, but also this seems cumbersome.

Am I missing something? Is there a better way to do this, or should I just build a utility to give me what I need?

**Old Update:**
Here is what I'm doing as a patch for now:

```
activatedRoute.pathFromRoot.find((parent: ActivatedRoute) => {
  return !!parent.snapshot.params[param];
})!;
```

`param` is the param I'm interested in finding.

Comment: Share a service between the component which has the param and its children. Store the param in the service from the component which has the param, get the param from the service in the child components.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks. I take it this means Angular does not have an efficient way to do this other than workarounds.

Comment: AFAIK, no, it doesn't. IIRC, there's a global configuration flag allowing to access parameters on any child, though. https://angular.io/api/router/ExtraOptions#paramsInheritanceStrategy

Comment: @JBNizet Interesting. I just tried a bit of searching but didn't find anything yet. I'll keep my eyes peeled.

Comment: I posted the link in my edited above comment. Refresh the page.

Comment: @JBNizet Holy moly, there it is. Setting `paramsInheritanceStrategy` to `'always'` did the trick. I now see the parent params in routes deeper than the level with the param I need. Big thanks.